# Show specific item from array in HTML

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show specific item depending on another value.

i have Dispensers array looking like:

```
{deviceID: 37, rack: 2, arm: 5, plu1: "4", plu2: "7"},
{deviceID: 38, rack: 2, arm: 6, plu1: "5", plu2: "8"},
{deviceID: 39, rack: 2, arm: 7, plu1: "6", plu2: "9"}
```

then when showing this data i want to show the PLU from my products table instead of the number

```
{pluNo:1, pluName:"Cola"},
{pluNo:4, pluName:"Sprite"},
{pluNo:5, pluName:"item3"},
{pluNo:6, pluName:"item3"},
{pluNo:7, pluName:"itemName"},
{pluNo:8, pluName:"itemName"},
{pluNo:9, pluName:"itemName"}
```

So i want to be able to print my dispensers but instead of showing the PLU number i would like to show the name, as it gives more sense.

printing out like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of dispensers; let i = index">                                                                                                                                                                     
    <td>                                                                                        
        {{item.rack}}                                                                                   
    </td>                                                                                   
    <td>                                                                                        
        {{item.arm}}                                                                                    
    </td>                                                                                   
    <td>                                                                                        
        {{item.plu1}}   //Want to show products.pluName with pluNo = item.plu1                                                                                                                                                                  
    </td>                                                                                                                       
    <td>                                                                                        
        {{item.plu2}}   //Want to show products.pluName with pluNo = item.plu2                                                                                  
    </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</tr>
```

tried:

```
{{products | filter : {'pluNo':item.plu1} }} //dont run
{{products[item.plu2].pluName}} // gives me pluName but by index instead of by pluNo
```

Comment: `pluName` is not inside your array. How can you display non existing data ?

Comment: It's in the products array though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to do

**Component Side :**

```
products = [{ pluNo: 1, pluName: "Cola" },
  { pluNo: 4, pluName: "Sprite" },
  { pluNo: 5, pluName: "item3" },
  { pluNo: 6, pluName: "item3" },
  { pluNo: 7, pluName: "itemName" },
  { pluNo: 8, pluName: "itemName" },
  { pluNo: 9, pluName: "itemName" }];

productsId = {};

constructor(){
    this.products.forEach(product => {
        this.productsId[product.pluNo] = product.pluName;
    })
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of dispensers; let i = index">
    {{ productsId[item.plu1] }}
    {{ productsId[item.plu2] }}
</tr>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-name-json)**

> Reason of being better is :
>
> As per @DanielB's solutions , from template side it will call the
>   function each time loops , and each time loops inside the function
>   also , so it will loops almost (no_of_records * no_of_records)
>
> ```
> getProductByPlu(id: string) {
>     return this.products.find((p) => p.pluNo.toString() === id);
> }
>
> {{getPluName(item.plu2).pluName}}
> ```

Comment: I see your point in making it only run thru the array once instead of 1 per. dispenser item

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that returns the product based on the PLU-code, something like

```
getProductByPlu(id: string) {
    return this.products.find((p) => p.pluNo.toString() === id);
}
```

and in your template call it with `{{getProductByPlu(item.plu2).pluName}}`.

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpytzm).

Comment: You named the 2 functions different, but its working perfectly thanks!